# Save Dictionary to XML file

Tags: .net, xml-serialization, c++-cli

I've been working on a text classification system and am trying to read words in text documents, parse it, save it to dictionary, then save it to an XML.

```
fileNames = openFileDialog1->FileNames;

StreamReader^ objReader = gcnew StreamReader(fileNames[0]);
String^ strReader = objReader->ReadToEnd();     //read it to a string
objReader->Close();

//cut the file up   
String^ delimStr = L"\r,\t,\n,' ','.',','"; //pull out the return,tabs,newline
array<Char>^ delimiter = delimStr->ToCharArray();//transform into an array
array<String^ > ^ strSplit = strReader->Split(delimiter);//split up the file
System::Collections::IEnumerator^ myenum = strSplit->GetEnumerator();//get enumerators 

Dictionary<String^, int>^ saveWords = gcnew Dictionary<String^, int>(StringComparer::InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
int position=-1;

//output the file
while (myenum->MoveNext())//enumerate through it
{
        position++;
        try{
            saveWords->Add((Convert::ToString(myenum->Current)),0);
        }
        catch (Exception ^){
            //some code
        }

}
```

So, how should I do the XMLSerializer?

P.S. Sorry if the code is a mess and un-optimized. I am new to all this (text parsing, dictionary, XML), and so far I'm just trying to make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should serialize Dictionary to XML file, there is a nice implemenatation here :

http://weblogs.asp.net/pwelter34/archive/2006/05/03/444961.aspx

**Update for FW 4+ (comment from Hearty):**

In order to work for the latest framework it is necessary to have a root element.

```
 In the WriteXML add a line:
 +49 writer.WriteStartElement("dictionary" ); 
 +70 writer.WriteEndElement( ); 

 In the ReadXML add lines 
 +27 reader.ReadStartElement( "dictionary" ); 
 +45 reader.ReadEndElement( )
```

;

Comment: Does this mean integrating a class and calling SerializableDictionary from the main code?

Comment: not sure that I understud you, but I thing that answer is yes. You have to use that new SerializableDictionary and then call WriteXml to get XML reprensentation of the dictionary

Comment: Isn't there an XMLSerializer which can be used since .Net 3.5? Or the only way is by using that custom class from the link you provided? 
I am asking this cause I've gotten errors. I don't know whether it's because of my poor/wrong implementation or it is really not supported.

Comment: do you resolve these problems ? This SerializableDictionary is written for 2.0 but should work for 3.5 and 4.x also

Comment: Yes, I've re-written my application using C# for it to work. Anyway there need to be slight modification for latest framework as in comment 

`In order to work for the latest framework it is necesairy to have a root element.

in the WriteXML add a line

+49 writer.WriteStartElement( "dictionary" );

+70 writer.WriteEndElement( );

in the ReadXML add lines

+27 reader.ReadStartElement( "dictionary" );

+45 reader.ReadEndElement( );`

Comment: Ah, sorry for my unclear wording. I didn't make the modification myself. I mean the modification comes from comment of link you give by someone named 'Johannes'.